# What is the relation between extensions and the backend of TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I am new to TYPO3 and have trouble understanding the general relation between extensions and the backend of TYPO3.

For example, is it true that the goal of making an extension is to be able add edited/new content elements to your page that cannot be found in TYPO3 out of the box?

For example if I wanted to add a carousel to my page, would I make an extension and design it in such a way that I can add it from my backend to the desired page? Or would it make more sense to, for example, put it as a partial and import it to the desired page using fluid (all of this without using the backend and just using code).

Or are both approaches possible and when would you go for the first or the second (or seek out a third approach)?

Sorry if this question is too general/vague. I feel like I do not understand how the backend and the files in my TYPO3 folder communicate to generate the website and that I am using content elements in the backend one time and typing out the elements in HTML the next time without a good reason for it.

Comment: No excuse required, is a good question

Answer (score 1):

I try to bring some light into the dark areas.

- **Backend** This is the admin area of the CMS where in most cases the content is created by editors.
- **Frontend**: How the website looks to a regular visitor
- **Extension**: An extension is custom code, either your own code or by others which extend TYPO3 in one or more ways. The benefit is that you don't change the code of TYPO3 core itself and therefore it can be always updated.

An extension can be used for a *lot of things*:
- Shipping a site template with all the assets like CSS, JavaScript, HTML template, ..
- Providing custom content elements
- Providing new record types like news or forms
- Improve user experience

So yes, if you want to have a new kind of content elements you need to use an extension:

- Search on https://extensions.typo3.org to check if there is already something which fits your needs
- Use https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/mask/ (best in combination with https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/mask_export/) or https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/dce/ to make it *a lot* faster to create content elements
- If experienced you can also create a custom content elements without any additional extension but for start I don't recommend that.